# Protect Firebase functions without auth

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

Is it possible to protect firebase http triggered functions without auth and accept calls only from my firebase hosted app?

I want my web app to call firebase functions with unauthenticated users but I don't want this functions to be accessible from anywhere else.

Comment: If you're willing to use Callable Cloud Functions, this is now possible with Firebase App Check. See my answer here for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67611797

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible to enforce.  All of your HTTP functions are accessible by all other clients out there, regardless of where they are in the world (unless something in their network is blocking them).

You could certainly make an attempt to guess if a request did not originate from your web site (by looking at the referrer header), but that information can be easily spoofed by an attacker.

Comment: So, is that means that Firebase is not the right platform to build PasteBin or 4chan like apps that users can post without logging in? or is there another way to guarantee that I can access the database only from my web app?

Comment: Hi @spiralout, did you find a solution for this issue? I'm dealing with exactly the same question.

Comment: Hi @Paolo, i think it is possible now, but haven't tested it. check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60191410/is-it-possible-to-only-accept-function-calls-from-my-app-in-firebase/67611797#67611797